# RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, list, serialization, gson, runtimetypeadapterfactory

I need help

When I trying to execute the following method

```java
public static GsonBuilder commonGsonBuilder(Map<Stix2Type, Class<? extends TypedStixObject>> customImplementations) {
        
    RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<TypedStixObject> factory =RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(TypedStixObject.class, "type", true);
            
    for (Stix2Type stix2Type : customImplementations.keySet()) {
        stix2Type.setImplementation(customImplementations.get(stix2Type));
    }

    for (Stix2Type value : Stix2Type.TYPES) {
        factory.registerSubtype(value.getImplementation(), value.toJsonString());
    }

    return new GsonBuilder()
        .disableHtmlEscaping() //without this patterns don't serialize correctly
        .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Collection.class, new EmptyCollectionNonSerializer())
        .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Stix2Type.class, new Stix2TypeSerializer())
        .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Stix2Type.class, new Stix2TypeDeserializer())
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(factory);
}
```

At the time of executing the following line

```
RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<TypedStixObject> factory =RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(TypedStixObject.class, "type", true);
```

it shows the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: types and labels must be unique 
at eu.csaware.stix2.common.RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.registerSubtype(RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java:162) 
at eu.csaware.stix2.util.Stix2Gson.commonGsonBuilder(Stix2Gson.java:39) 
at eu.csaware.stix2.util.Stix2Gson.commonGsonBuilder(Stix2Gson.java:25)
at eu.csaware.stix2.util.Stix2Gson.<clinit>(Stix2Gson.java:21) ... 2 more
```

I am using java 8 and I can not use List.of

I think that is why is showing the error

How can I replace this line

```
RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<TypedStixObject> factory =RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(TypedStixObject.class, "type", true);
```

many thanks in advance
ana

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace.

Comment: Hello Samadcde,

thank you for you help

this is the stacktrace

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: types and labels must be unique
 at eu.csaware.stix2.common.RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.registerSubtype(RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java:162)
 at eu.csaware.stix2.util.Stix2Gson.commonGsonBuilder(Stix2Gson.java:39)
 at eu.csaware.stix2.util.Stix2Gson.commonGsonBuilder(Stix2Gson.java:25)
 at eu.csaware.stix2.util.Stix2Gson.<clinit>(Stix2Gson.java:21)
 ... 2 more

Comment: found the error. As the trace said I have the same  type twice.
..............Thank you

Comment: Good to hear you solve it, looking at the stacktrace usually help you to solve the problem. Please also post your answer.